# How to Calculate the Positive Feedback as per rating in php

Tags: php, percentage, feedback

Different users of the site are giving rating of the seller. I want to calculate the positive feedback in percentage of seller. I am showing the database of the single seller 
In My Feedback table data is storing as follow :

**Note** :
reliable max : 5, 
communication max : 5, 
experience max : 3 (1=poor, 2= average, 3 = good)

**User one** rating to Seller
reliable : 4
communication : 5
experience : 3

**User two** rating to Seller
reliable : 5
communication : 1
experience : 2

**User three** rating to Seller
reliable : 5
communication : 5
experience : 3

and other users rating will go in this fashion

how do i calculate the Positive feedback of the Seller?

Comment: Calculate the average for each seller (eg. 4 + 5 + 3 / 3) and then the average for all sellers?

Answer (score 3):

```
select avg((reliable + communication + experience)/3) as feedback
from Feedbacktable  group by sellerid
```

Answer (score 0):

Get it as

```
$total = 0
$avg = 0
foreach ($users as $user) {
   $user_avg = ($user['reliable'] + $user['communication'] + ($user['experience']/3) * 5) / 3;
   $total += $user_avg;
}
if (sizeof($users) > 0) {
  $avg = $total/sizeof($users);
  $avg = round($avg, 2)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have applied your code in a sample database and it is giving response in a very less number below 5 ... I want to transfer my database sql to you so that u can understand the database structure easily. So can i get your mail id or any other way of communication ?